# How to detect file within folder with python?

Tags: python, directory, os.path

My code:

```
name = "test.txt"
if os.path.isfile("../datafiles/"+name):
        print "Error; File already exists"
```

the folder datafiles sits in the same directoy as the python file, i'm trying to check for a file inside that folder. The above code can't detect the file, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The given code doesnt detect the file inside the folder datafiles, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: it is working fine for me on windows. are you trying it on linux ?

Comment: Use absolute path.

Comment: Because you're doing `../`, that travers your lookup one step backwards in your folder structure. try `./`

Comment: How have you set up your directory structure?

Comment: Torxed answer works, thanks

Comment: @user6240030 Please mark the question as answered if that's the case. We like a tidy ship at StackOverflow and unanswered questions will be in the deep pits of "never solved questions" otherwise. Welcome to SO and hope we could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `datafiles` resides in the same folder as your script.
Then you can't do `../` because that steps "out" of the folder one step back..

Meaning if your script+datafiles sits in `/home/user/`, your script will check `/home/datafiles/test.txt`, and that doesn't exist.

Change your path to `./` or absolute paths.

```
name = "test.txt"
if os.path.isfile("./datafiles/"+name):
        print "Error; File already exists"
```

Or pref, `"/home/user/the/full/path/to/datafiles/"+name`.